# VueJS in-line template and v-for in it

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use in-line template that I have for dropdown menus but it's messing up the things upon switching between states.
This is the code I use in the main template:

```
<div>
<article v-for="(game, index) in games">
<dropdown ref="dropdown" inline-template>
<a v-for="(branch, index) in game.branches" :key="'branch' + index" :href="branch.link">{{ branch.name }}</a>
</dropdown>
</article>
</div>
```

It's working fine on load, but when I switch between categories the links are messing up, and the same links from the load stay for the other renders.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you please provide more code, also how do you switch between categories? Can we see the code for that as well? The best option would be to reproduce your example on CodeSandbox or a similar tool.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html).

> *In 2.2.0+, when using v-for with a component, a key is now required.*

For that reason you should be using `:key` in `v-for`.

You can assign your key to index or make it even more unique like:

`:key="'branch'+index"`

in case if you used similar keys before in your component (key should be unique).

Comment: Upvoted because the answer is the same as my answer and we both published at the same time :)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing to set an unique `:key` on the `a` tag.
The key, needs to be a unique identifier for the looped element. In the example below I'm using the index of the current looped element, but thats just for the sake of the example. Usually is not considered good practice to use the index because it can change forcing elements to re - render.
You will note that the name of the var holding the indexes in the v-for are different:
the indexes var needs to have unique names too, or the index in the inner loop will "steal" the index from the outer loop.

```
<article v-for="(game, gIndex) in games" :key="gIndex">
   <dropdown ref="dropdown" inline-template>
      <a v-for="(branch, bIndex) in branches"
        :key="gIndex+bIndex" 
        :href="branch.link">
            {{ branch.name }}
      </a>
   </dropdown>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that, but unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem... :(

Comment: I've updated my question, as I'm using the dropdown component in another <article> element which also is iterating and the branches are changes based on games.

Comment: @AnTrakS Your code still doesn't show the use of a `:key` anywhere. I'd suggest updating your code showing what you tried that isn't working.

Comment: @AnTrakS I've updated my answer to show you how to use :key in both the loops

Comment: @Raffobaffo Adding the indexes would not create unique keys